# Akka HTTP Client EntityStreamSizeException

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to send a get request to my localhost using Akka HTTP and I get the following exception:

```
EntityStreamSizeException: actual entity size (Some(10166731700)) exceeded content length limit (8388608 bytes)! You can configure this by setting akka.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length or calling HttpEntity.withSizeLimit before materializing the dataBytes stream.)
```

Basically, the file on my localhost which I'm trying to request is very large.

I tried to solve it by using `withoutSizeLimit`, but it's not working:

```
val request = Get("http://localhost:8080/oa-ok.ntriples")
val limitedRequest = request.withEntity(request.entity.withoutSizeLimit())
val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(limitedRequest)
```

I also tried to use `withSizeLimit` and it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use `withoutSizeLimit` on the response entity, not the request entity. For example:

```
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:8080/oa-ok.ntriples"))

val responseSource: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromFuture(responseFuture)
    .flatMapConcat(_entity.withoutSizeLimit.dataBytes)
```

`responseSource` is an Akka Streams `Source` of the response entity.